# Connecting to Naturally Speaking through SAPI 4 interface, possible?

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi, naturallyspeaking

I read somewhere that you can interface to Naturally Speaking through the SAPI 4 interface it exports? Is this true and is there any documentation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. Documentation on old MSDN cds.

Answer (score 2):

I've found several news releases from Dragon claiming that an older version of Naturally Speaking supported SAPI 4.0.  The problem is that SAPI 4.0 has been obsolete for over a decade; MSDN doesn't even bother to document it.  I suppose if you could get a 1999-era archive copy of MSDN on DVD, you could use that.

I'm also not sure that current versions of Naturally Speaking continue to support SAPI 4.

Final answer:  True at one time; probably not true now.

Comment: current versions do support sapi 4.